# Memory Saving capabilities of Python Generators when you require a list ultimately

Tags: python, generator

I have been facing some situations where I produce a generator through generator comprehension or a function like in the following examples:

**Function**

```
def return_labels(self,x_y):
        yield x_y[1]
```

**Generator Comprehension**

```
nums_squared_gc = (i ** 2 for i in range(10000))
```

In both cases generators are produced, however ultimately I need a list in order to use it for other purposes.

**Memory consumption of Generator**

```
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(nums_squared_gc))
>>> 112
```

**Memory Consumption when the above generator is made to a list**

```
>>> sys.getsizeof([i for i in nums_squared_gc])
>>> 87616
```

From what I can see, at the end of the day, I still end up consuming the same amount of bytes.

Is there a better way to iterate through a generator, else is it better to use list comprehension regardless, whenever you intend to use all the values produced from the generator?

Comment: If you need the entire list as a list, then both lists are going to use the same amount of memory and the generator will probably be a little bit slower.  But the real question is which makes your code the most readable.

Comment: The only way to really answer this question is to understand *why* you need a list, and to explore ways to refactor and remove that requirement. Can provide an example of how you need to use the list currently?

Comment: @daveruinseverything Currently, the list is a list of tuples. Im sorting it to get the key with the largest value in the (key,value) pair. I'm guessing given that I'm using the entire list for this process, list comprehension is better here?

Comment: @PasinduSamaranayake you can pass a generator to `max` and pass a `key` function to get the largest value without converting to a list and sorting

Comment: @IainShelvington yes this works for my requirement. Didnt know I could do this, thank you for the tip.